# Problems setting up GLFW on Arch Linux

Tags: c++, linux, glfw

I use Linux, more specifically, Arch Linux. I wanted to work with OpenGL, so I did the following steps:

1. First, I downloaded the `glfw-x11` with the `pacman` package manager.
2. I also used `cmake` to add `glfw` to `/usr/local/include`, everything works fine.
3. I wrote a Makefile to run my program with the command:

   ```
   gcc -o demo main.c -lglfw3 -lm -lXrandr -lXi -lXxf86vm -lpthread
   ```

> Also note that I removed `-lGl` because `gcc`, the compiler, screamed at me.

Here is my project directory: `glad main.c Makefile`. Note that `glad` is a directory. And it works fine.

I am running on Linux so I can't install **Visual Studio** and I am really don't think I need **CodeBlocks** to create an OpenGL project.

The error the compiler gives me when I run this code (in `main.c`):

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "glad/glad.h"
  #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
  
  int main() {
      glfwInit();
  
      printf("Hello, OpenGL!");
      // Code goes here..
 
      glfwTerminate();
      return 0;
  }
```

The compiler gave me:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XPending'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Edit**

`lGL` just worked, but still I get the same error.

**Another Edit**

Adding `-ldl`, `lXinerama` and `lXcursor` worked for me.

**Final Edit**

I fixed it, first, you create a `main.cpp` (or whatever you wanna call it). Make sure you have `libgl`, `glu` and `glfw-x11` installed. Then create a `Makefile` with the flags `-lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 -lm -lXrandr -lXi -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpthread -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor`. Then download glad. Extract `glad.zip` (Make sure glad is in the project folder). Move `src/glad.c` into the project directory. Include `glad` with `"include/glad/glad.h"` or whatever directory you choose. Also make sure GLFW is in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Have you tried `-lX11`?

Comment: Yes, and I finally get no errors. But I have no window showing up (I edited the `main.c` code). And I am sure that it is valid code.

Comment: It is valid code. But there's no code for opening a window. You only initialize the library, but you nowhere open a window. See https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_creation

Comment: You don't need to guess the flags. Get the flags from `pkg-config`.

Comment: Hey @BDL, I deleted the code above and wrote code that will open a window from Victor Gordan's tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z03LXhRBLGI&t=271s

Comment: I really forgot about that @HolyBlackCat, thanks, but I tried with `pkconfig --cflags --libs glfw gl` and they are not found..

Comment: I think the problem is not with GLFW or GLAD, they both work perfectly. But the problem is that windows that should be shown are not shown. I also have `mesa` btw

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the drivers, the Arch Wiki says that you can't run any OpenGL application without installing `mesa` drivers: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenGL#Installation

Comment: Try `pkg-config --list-all`, maybe they're named differently.

Comment: `pkg-config --list-all`, and maybe use `grep` to search for the name of a package. Btw GLFW is called `glfw3` not `glfw`, at least on my system.